# Fisher information for uniform distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution, point-estimation

If I want to compute the CRLB for iid uniform on $[0,\theta]$. I need in the denominator this expression: $E_\theta\left[\left(\frac{\partial \log f(X)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\right]=nE_\theta\left[\left(\frac{\partial \log f(x)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\right]$.

Notation edit: $X\equiv(X_1,...,X_n)$ and $x\equiv x_1$.
In this case we have:

\begin{align}
f(X) &=\theta^{-n}  \tag{1} \\
\log f(X) &=-n\log \theta  \tag{2} \\
\frac{\partial \log f(X)}{\partial \theta} &=\frac{-n}{\theta}  \tag{3} \\
\left(\frac{\partial \log f(X)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2 &=\frac{n^2}{\theta^2}  \tag{4} \\
E_\theta\left[\left(\frac{\partial \log f(X)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\right] &=\frac{n^2}{\theta^2}\neq \frac{n}{\theta^2}=nE_\theta\left[\left(\frac{\partial \log f(x)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\right] \tag{5} 
\end{align}

I can't see where I am making a mistake.

Comment: I think it has to do with interchanging differentiation and expectation, which usually fails in the Uniform Distribution, but can't see why.

Comment: The CRLB does not apply for the uniform distribution, because the support of the distribution depends on the parameter $\theta$, one of the required regularity conditions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound.

Comment: For uniform distributions like the one on $[0,\theta]$, there exist super-efficient estimators that converge faster than $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: You would also need to keep track of the indicator function in the defition of the likelihood, which is $\theta^{-n}\mathbb{I}(\max_iX_i\leq\theta)$

Comment: Understanding this question is problematic. If "$x$" means "$X$" then the first equation is obviously false in general (because both expectations are the same but one of them is multiplied by $n$) whereas if "$x$" is something else, then the expectation on the right hand side is meaningless: where is the random variable?

Comment: Will it be true that under the uniform distribution, the score not necessarily has expectation equal to zero?

Comment: Under the Uniform, the score function has an expectation _different_  from $0$.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/389065/119261.