# Cramèr-Rao lower bound on the variance of an unbiased estimator

Tags: inference

When is the variance of an unbiased estimator lower than the Cramèr-Rao lower bound ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For distributions that do not satisfy the conditions for the Cramèr-Rao lemma to apply, e.g. for these which support depends on the parameter, there is [no reason](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2742267/14893) for the Cramèr-Rao inequality to hold. See for instance this example from Casella & Berger (Example 7.3.13), when $$X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\mathcal{U}(0,\theta)$$ the estimator $$\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}$$ is unbiased and with variance $\theta^2/n(n+2)$ while the Cramèr-Rao lower bound is $\theta^2/n$. (See [this entry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/372347/7224) on X validated about the Fisher information for Uniforms, which some argue does not exist. I tend to agree.)

Comment: Indeed the Fisher information $I(\theta)$ does not exist here (we can arrive at different expressions for $I(\theta)$ using different formulae). But does the CR inequality really apply in these cases since the regularity conditions are not satisfied?

Comment: @StubbornAtom: The Cramèr-Rao bound lemma applies under regularity conditions that are not satisfied by the Uniform distribution, there is thus no surprise whatsoever that it is not a valid bound on the unbiased estimator in the Uniform case. The OP was apparently asking for cases as such.